# How to iterate through items in a list that have commas in them?

Tags: python, list, arguments

I have a class instance:

```
self.robots = ROBOT()
```

And I want to run my code such that I will have the following arguments passed into it:

```
bestBrains[overallChampionIndex],-8,0
bestBrains[overallChampionIndex],-4,-4
bestBrains[overallChampionIndex],-4,4
```

In successive iterations.

So the first iteration will be:
`self.robots = ROBOT(bestBrains[overallChampionIndex],-8,0)`

The second iteration will be:
`self.robots = ROBOT(bestBrains[overallChampionIndex],-4,-4)`

The third iteration will be:
`self.robots = ROBOT(bestBrains[overallChampionIndex],-4,4)`

I tried the following:

```
        self.position = [
            (bestBrains[overallChampionIndex],-8,0),
            (bestBrains[overallChampionIndex],-4,-4),
            (bestBrains[overallChampionIndex],-4,4),
            (bestBrains[overallChampionIndex],0,-8),
            (bestBrains[overallChampionIndex],0,0),
            (bestBrains[overallChampionIndex],0,8),
            (bestBrains[overallChampionIndex],4,-4),
            (bestBrains[overallChampionIndex],4,0),
            (bestBrains[overallChampionIndex],4,4),
            (bestBrains[overallChampionIndex],8,0) 
        ]
```

```
        self.robots = ROBOT(self.position[positionIndex])
```

```
          self.robots[self.position[i]]
```

ROBOT takes in 3 arguments, and my attempt resulted in only the first argument being satisfied.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-double-star-asterisk-and-star-asterisk-do-for-parameters

Comment: I've read through the post. I don't see how this is applicable to my problem.

Answer (score 1):

as suggested in the comment you can use the asterisk operator this way:

```
self.robots[*self.position[i]]
```

or simply by accessing the elements of your tuple this way:

```
self.robots[self.position[i][0], self.position[i][1],  self.position[i][2]]
```